# Removing patterns only from 1st column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following informations:

```
'>16_R_I_1_0 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15012:1778 1:N:0:0 orig_bc=CGGAGCTATGGT new_bc=CGGAGCTATGGT bc_diffs=0  
'>0_V_I_2_2 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:16237:1790 1:N:0:0 orig_bc=CTAGCGAACATC new_bc=CTAGCGAACATC bc_diffs=0
```

I want to remove the "_" only from the first column. I used the command like this:  `sed "$1=/s/\_//g"`, but it is not working. I want the output like this:

```
'>16RI10 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15012:1778 1:N:0:0 orig_bc=CGGAGCTATGGT new_bc=CGGAGCTATGGT bc_diffs=0  
'>0VI22 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:16237:1790 1:N:0:0 orig_bc=CTAGCGAACATC new_bc=CTAGCGAACATC bc_diffs=0
```

any suggestion please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ gsub("_", "", $1); print }'
```

Explanation:

```
awk '{                         for each line
      gsub(                    globally replace
           "_", ""             underscore by the empty string
           $1);                in the first column
      print                    and print the modified line
     }'
```

Comment: thanks for your nice suggestion and breakdown of the command.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e ':a;s/^\( *[^ _]*\)_/\1/;ta' data.genefile
```

Will remove all `_` from the first field only in the input genefile.

---

### Perl

```
perl -F'(\s+)' -lne 'print map { /\S/ && !$a++ && s/_//g; $_ } @F' datagene.txt
```

### Explanation

- `-F'(\s+)'` => `FS` = one or more whitespace(s). The brackets modify the behavior in that now the fields array `@F` comprises the intervening whitespace which in the normal case is lost. We do this to maintain the whitesoace before and after the change.
- `map { ... }` command operates on the fields array `@F` elements one-by-one and the boolean logic is put in place to ensure that only the first nonempty field is operated upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 'h;s/ .*//;s/_//g;G;s/\n[^ ]*//'
```

Explanation: The `h` copies the line in the hold space, the first `s` removes everything but the first field, the second does the desired replacement. Then you append the hold space with `G` and remove the newline with the first field. Done.